# Received a new Tektronix AFG1022 function generator, I would like to see if I could output a higher amplitude using a transformer or amplifier

Tags: function-generator

I'd like to operate in a 0-12 V range, I would like to see what the best option would be to increase the voltage at the output. Our maximum frequency is 1Hz if there may be an issue with attenuation.

Comment: Just stick an op amp in there, at 1Hz you shouldn't have any problems. A transformer rated for 1Hz operation would be really difficult to find.

Comment: would i just stick any op amp with a certain gain? I am new to the industrial experience.

Comment: divide output_you_want by output_you've_got, and that's the gain of the amplifier you want.

Comment: What's the lowest frequency you expect to use?  The AFG1022 goes down to 1 microhertz (11.5 days per cycle.)  If you get into that kind of stuff it becomes more difficult.

Comment: What are you connecting that 12V output to? How much current do you expect it to take? The opamp solution will only be good up to 10 or 20mA, which won't drive power-hungry loads.

Answer (score 0):

Opamps will be current-limited by internal high-current-detection circuits.

If you need higher voltage and high current, some companies make hybrid (metal can) opamps.

At one Hertz, you might use a Kepco 4-quadrant power supply, programmable to a variable Vout.